# How to solve Wordpress 404 error msg

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Whenever I update a post, I get a "Connection lost. Saving has been disabled until you’re reconnected.” that laters turns into a 404 error message. I never get the error msg when I create a new one. I have tried a couple of things, like checked all of my plugins, updated the permalinks, looked at the code, but cannot find anything.

I have around 20 000 views a week, and I have one CPU core. Should I get one more CPU core?

All help is appriciated!

Comment: 20K views a week is ~2 per minute on average, and it ought to easily cope with a magnitude or two more requests than that. But you can hopefully monitor CPU load from your host to see. I wouldn't expect 404 from a load issue, though. I'd check what request your browser was making in the debug tools and look on the server for any error logs too when you have this error if you haven't already.

Comment: @Rup I didnt get any errors when I checked the logs. And the site crashes only when I update a post. Do you think that my one CPU core is enough?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is your mod_Security setup. You haven't provided any information on your hosting setup. Here's some general guidelines that may only help in a dedicated or VPS environment. If you're on a shared server running cPanel, you may have the ability to only turn mod_security on/off via cPanel which isn't advisable (though it should solve the problem). On a dedicated or VPS box, you should have the ability to tweak your mod_security rules and resolve the problem:

1. Locate whitelist.conf, might be in /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2/whitelist.conf.
2. Add the following rules to the file:

   ```
   <LocationMatch “/wp-admin/post.php”>
   SecRuleRemoveById 300015 300016 300017
   </LocationMatch>

   <LocationMatch “/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php”>
   SecRuleRemoveById 300015 300016 300017
   </LocationMatch>

   <LocationMatch “/wp-admin/page.php”>
   SecRuleRemoveById 300015 300016 300017
   </LocationMatch>
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Restart Apache

Comment: Thank you! I havent done anything with the hosting setup. I bought a service where I dont need to do anything on the hosting side. Is there a way of turning on/off the mod_Securetiy instead of changing the code?